# Passing value PHP (Online Cart)

Tags: php, mysql, post

So I am making a php page where it will receive all the data from the previous php page. I have already displayed the list of the products but everytime I click the add to cart button, it only reads the quantity of the last product.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$dib = $row['db_prod_id'];
$Item_ID =$row['bbs_prod_id'];
$Item_Name =$row['prod_name'];
$Item_Description =$row['description'];
    $Price =$row['price'];
$Item_Image =$row['item_image'];

echo "<input type='hidden' name='dib' value='$dib'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$Item_ID'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='name' value='$Item_Name'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='desc' value='$Item_Description'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='price' value='$Price'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='img' value='$Item_Image'>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<th><label>$Item_ID</label></th>";
echo "<th><label>$Item_Name</label></th>";
echo "<th><label>$Item_Description</label></th>";
echo "<th><label>$Price</label></th>";
echo "<th><img src='$Item_Image' height='100' width='100'></th>";
echo "<th><input type='text' value='' placeholder='how many' name='quantity'>";

echo "<th><input type='submit' value='Add to Cart'></th>";
echo "<tr>";
```

I only test the passing of quantity.
Only the last item echoes a quantity.

```
session_start();

$user = $_SESSION['bbs_buyer_login'];

require("dbconnect.php");

$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

echo "$quantity";
```

I already have 3 items on my list but only the third item echoes a quantity and is only being read everytime I click the 'add to cart' button.

Help please. Thank you!

Comment: `$_POST` derives from the HTTP request, you need to store the `$_POST` data in the `$_SESSION` to re-use it on a separate request.

Answer (score 0):

You're inside loop. Change your input to be treated as array:

```
echo "<th><input type='text' value='' placeholder='how many' name='quantity[]'>";
```

Then `$_POST['quantity']` will be an array with quantities. You can lookup this via

```
print_r($_POST['quantity']);
```

or

```
var_dump($_POST['quantity']);
```

I don't know how rest of your code works, but it should do the trick in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` derives from the HTTP request you're sending to the server containing an array `key => value` of the `name` and `value` of the inputs.

To store the quantity and later add to it, you need to use your cookies/sessions. Firstly, instance the cart array like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}
```

You can then set the product id (`$pid`) and the quantity (`$q`) in this array like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['quantity']) && isset($_POST['id']) {
    $q = $_POST['quantity'];
    $pid = (int) $_POST['id'];
    $c = $_SESSION['cart'];
    $c[$pid] = $c[$pid] ? $c[$pid] + (int) $q : (int) $q;
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $c;
}
```

Then, to later see the products to their quantity simply run an SQL query on each product.

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $pid => $q) {
    // change SQL to meet your DB
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = :product_id LIMIT 1';
    $stmt = $pdo->Prepare($sql); // using PDO driver
    $stmt->bind_param(':product_id', (int) $pid); // dont trust the data
    $stmt->execute();
    $r = $stmp->fetch();
    $cost = $r['price'] * $q; // get the price and multiply by quantity
}
```